# In a table, if column A value is enforced to be unique, why does this imply there will not be any duplicate row?

Tags: linear-algebra

Initially when I was designing a table with column A, B. I didn't want to have any duplicated rows so I enforce

UNIQUE(A, B)

This table with following rows is not valid

```
 A | B
-------
 1 | 2
 1 | 2
```

Subsequently, I want column A to be unique so I enforce another rule

UNIQUE(A)

This table with following rows is not valid

```
 A | B
-------
 1 | 2
 1 | 3
```

this makes me realize that rule UNIQUE(A, B) no longer needed and is redundant.

Although it is very intuitive to think about, I am wondering if there is any mathematical proof for this kind of relationship? Can it extend to be applied for the statement like

"For row (A_1, A_2, A_3, .... , A_n), if any column is enforced to be unique, all row will be unique"

Comment: What is UNIQUE(...)?

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification, UNIQUE means it is unique as a pair in the case of (A,B) or unique as an element in case of (A)

Answer (score 1):

If all the elements along a column are different, then each row will differ at that column, and will thus all be different.